# Can I add a custom (spoofed) X-Forwarded-For and Via Header in Squid for requests from local network?

Tags: squid

I tried spoofing the X-Forwarded-For Header (and Via Header) in Squid in my local network. Since the request isn't coming from a system with a public ip, I assume that squid doesn't set these headers (They are turned on by default, but aren't present in requests). I tried adding them with `request_header_add X-Forwarded-For "10.0.0.0" all` and also rebuilt squid with the `--enable-http-violations` flag set ([source](https://donjajo.com/spoof-http-headers-using-squid-proxy-server/)). But they still wouldn't appear.

The spoof of another header like User-Agent - that was present in the requests before - was possible this way by using `request_header_access <header> deny all` and `request_header_replace <header> <NewValue>`. But X-Forwarded-For still isn't present.

Is there a way to add X-Forwarded-For and the Via to requests coming from the local network with a custom value?

Comment: This sounds somewhat like an X-Y problem. What are you attempting to achieve?